# Firebase auth is not working on chrome

Tags: javascript, authentication, firebase

I don't know when it happened because as I was developing I had a started session in my browser so I didn't have to login through providers as Google or Facebook again. When a new user tried to login in my web app she told me that there was an error. So I cleaned my browser data and started to have the message `A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.` when the browser try to open a popup of Google or Facebook login. It doesn't happen in Safari or in my Android Chrome.

Here's a code snippet as reference.

```
<!--
@license
Copyright (c) 2016 The Polymer Project Authors. All rights reserved.
This code may only be used under the BSD style license found at http://polymer.github.io/LICENSE.txt
The complete set of authors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/AUTHORS.txt
The complete set of contributors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/CONTRIBUTORS.txt
Code distributed by Google as part of the polymer project is also
subject to an additional IP rights grant found at http://polymer.github.io/PATENTS.txt
-->

<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymerfire/polymerfire.html">
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">

<dom-module id="my-view1">
  <template>
    <style include="shared-styles">
      :host {
        display: block;

        padding: 10px;
      }   
    </style>

   <div class="card">
      <div class="circle">1</div>
      <paper-button on-tap="login">Login</paper-button >
      <h1>View One</h1>
      <p>Ut labores minimum atomorum pro. Laudem tibique ut has.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, per in nusquam nominavi periculis, sit elit oportere ea.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, per in n#
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-view1',

      login: function(){//{{{
        firebase.initializeApp({
          apiKey: apiKey,
          authDomain: authDomain,
          databaseURL: databaseURL
        });

        var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
        firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result){
          console.log(result);
        }).catch(function(error){
          console.error( error);
        });
      },//}}}
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should initialise the app before someone clicks on Login.

```
firebase.initializeApp({
   apiKey: apiKey,
   authDomain: authDomain,
   databaseURL: databaseURL
});
```

Whenever someone lands on page maybe the best place to do this.

Comment: Nah.. is not it. I have test it.

Answer (score 0):

I went to [chrome://settings/content/cookies](http://chrome://settings/content/cookies) and clicked **Remove all**. That fixed it for me.